# getting 404, firebase + node.js, using "projects.locations.instances.create"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make an instance of a database with node.js in firebase realtime database.

My node.js route looks like this:

```
const axios = require('axios');
var {google} = require("googleapis");
var serviceAccount = require("paht/to/json");

router.post('/createnewdatabase', function (req, res) {

//scopes used for the create
var scopes = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"
];

// Authenticate a JWT client with the service account.
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  serviceAccount.client_email,
  null,
  serviceAccount.private_key,
  scopes
);

// Use the JWT client to generate an access token.
jwtClient.authorize(function(error, tokens) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error making request to generate access token:", error);
  } else if (tokens.access_token === null) {
    console.log("Provided service account does not have permission to generate access tokens");
  } else {
      var accessToken = tokens.access_token;

      let apiKey = req.body.apiKey;

      const config = {
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
          },
      };
  
      axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://firebasedatabase.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/{project-id}/locations/europe-west1',
      data: {
          key: apiKey,   
          databaseId: 'segesggseg-656-sdgsdgs',
      },
      config
      })
      .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
  
      res.send('POST request to the homepage')
    }
});
```

})

I'm getting a 404 when trying to call the route. I'm guessing it's something with the tokens. The documentation is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/database-management/rest/v1beta/projects.locations.instances/create

I can't figure it out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider that according to the official documetation [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/database-management/rest/v1beta/projects.locations.instances#DatabaseInstance):

"name field  - Currently the only supported location is **'us-central1'**."

I was able to create an instance using the api only with empty data parameter.

```
  'https://firebasedatabase.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/111111111111/locations/us-central1/instances?databaseId=myinstanceiddd&validateOnly=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{}' \
  --compressed
```

```
200
{
  "name": "projects/111111111111/locations/us-central1/instances/myinstanceiddd",
  "project": "projects/111111111111",
  "databaseUrl": "https://myinstanceiddd.firebaseio.com",
  "type": "USER_DATABASE",
  "state": "ACTIVE"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After answer above did not work for me... I was forced to **read docs** (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/database-management/rest/v1beta/projects.locations.instances/create) **word by word**...

Second paragraph says that **ur project needs to be on the Blaze plan** in order to be able to create instance... After this doing this, it now works for me.